# AngularJS broadcast event fires $on in own scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, broadcast

I am implementing event reflector directive. Its sole purpose is to listen to an event and broadcast it down to children scopes. Reason is: I have couple of components that need to communicate with each other but they not in direct parent-child relation (lets say they as siblings).

```
<div reflector="customEvent">
  <component1...></component1>
  <component2...></component2>
</div>
```

If I want to raise an event "customEvent" in component1 and catch it in component2 I would place my reflector directive in the parent scope. This will resend event back to all children thus reaching component2. Here is directive:

```
angular.module('tripactions')
.directive('reflector', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var ignore = false;
        scope.$on(attrs.reflector, function(data) {
            if (!ignore) {
                ignore = true;
                scope.$broadcast(attrs.reflector, data);
            }
            ignore = false;
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Problem is it looks like calling broadcast from scope in directive also raises event in the same scope thus creating infinite loop. I thought it should raise events only in the children (at least according to what I read). How do I broadcast event to only children or go around my current problem?

Edit1: I updated original code and added ignore flag to block broadcast to self. Feels hackish but I dont know any other way.

Comment: Personally I would look to using a service first to do all this. Seems strange to rebroadcast events. If must do it use an identifier in each component to know what source of emitter is

Comment: The simplest way to propagate scope events to sibling components is to broadcast from `$rootScope` i.e. `scope.$root.$broadcast("my-event",data);`.

Comment: @georgeawg that would be excessive since you may want to communicate between 2 siblings within reusable component. Imagine I have 10 components on the page. Doing something to one will trigger all 10. I always stay away from broadcasting from the rootScope and use it as last resort.

Comment: @charlietfl can you give an example of service communication?

Comment: **Best Practice:** Only use `.$broadcast()`, `.$emit()` and `.$on()` for atomic events that are relevant globally across the entire app (such as a user authenticating or the app closing). If you want events specific to modules, services or widgets you should consider Services, Directive Controllers, or 3rd Party Libs. For more information, see [AngularJS Wiki -- Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices).